# How to set object value at the time of application is lunch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova

In my **angular js + cordova + ionic app**, I want to set my **database** object at the time of application launch. I intialize it in **app.js** file.

`.run(function ($ionicPlatform, DBService, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("CO.db");
            DBService.setDB(db);
...}`

and I am going to retrive that **db object** on anothe file using this function **DBService.getDB();**.

Problem is that in .controller `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/contact');` function load cotact-ctrl.js file first but not not load the **db object**. and after completion of the load of cotact-ctrl.js file it execute the .run method in app.js file thats why it not get the **db object**

Actually I am new in angular js and I don't know the angular js app life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating db object as local to your ready event scope. That why it will not be available outside of that handler.

You need to move db at global scope. This way you can access it anywhere in your application.

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, DBService, $cordovaSQLite) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            window.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("CO.db");
            DBService.setDB(db);
...}
```

Comment: but I am using getter and setter method. and also when my page is contact page is launch it stillnot get the db object values

Comment: When do you bootstrap your application? Ideally, you should bootstrap you application in device.ready event of cordova in your case $ionicPlatform.ready. Then your run block will execute first then any other controller. Only problem with your code is your are attaching an event on your run block. That's why it's executing after your controller.